# How to SET y-axis and x-axis variables in HISTOGRAM, matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[58858.08592372685,58858.092918055554,58858.13817175926,58858.148694675925,58858.15920509259]

y=[7.5,10.8,5.9,6.7,6.8]

data=[x,y]

plt.hist(data,bins=20)
plt.show()
```

x-axis is the date in Julian calendar and y-axis are my values. I want to draw a histogram using x and y arrays.
The format should be: x[0] and y[0], then x[1] and y[1], etc.
However, the graph only outputs two values.

Comment: `plt.hist(y, bins=20)`. I suppose in reality you have more than 5 values, otherwise the 20 bins will mostly be empty.

Comment: frankly, i do not understanding bins job, so giving anything values

Comment: It seems you want to draw a bar graph, not a histogram.  Maybe `plt.bar(x, y, width=0.005)`. A histogram puts all values into bins (e.g. counting how many y values go into each of 20 bins).  A bar graph just creates bars with a given height.

Comment: Bars that are 5 minutes wide, and x values in hours starting from the start of the julian day: `plt.bar(24*(np.array(x)-58858), y, width=5/60)`

Comment: i used plt.bar, but y and x values of the graph it creates are different from my arrays

Comment: Please edit the code of the post to explain the exact issue